# what is the difference between these two usages of wrapper function?

Tags: javascript

These two usages below seem work fine:

1. wrapper function without return

```js
document.querySelector(`button`).addEventListener(`click`, delayedClickButton);

const timeout = 1000;
function delayedClickButton(evt) {
  setTimeout(
      function (){clickButton(evt)},
      timeout
    );
}

function clickButton(evt) {
  evt.target.style.color = `red`;
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

2. wrapper function with return

```js
document.querySelector(`button`).addEventListener(`click`, delayedClickButton);

const timeout = 1000;
function delayedClickButton(evt) {
  setTimeout(
      function (){return clickButton(evt);},
      timeout
    );
}

function clickButton(evt) {
  evt.target.style.color = `red`;
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Which one is correct when I want a click event handling function that is delayed for 1 second, and I want to access the target element in that function by using evt.target.

Comment: There is no difference. The `setTimeout` callback doesn’t return anywhere. And `clickButton` itself doesn’t return anything. What do you expect `return` to do here?

Comment: Either one will "work" but I would prefer _not_ to use the `return` statement since it actually isn't returning a value that you would consume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return statement isn't needed so the first example is better, although they both work.
returns are useful for when we want to do something with a resulting value e.g.

```js
const myFunc = ()=>{
  return 'I returned something'
}

console.log(myFunc())
```